# How to calculate 3 most repeated values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Accout | paid Date | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5THJU |  | Not Paid |
| NH987 | 01/05/2021 | Paid |
| 5THJU | 01/05/2021 | Paid |
| GTK09 | 01/07/2021 | Paid |
| NH987 |  | Not Paid |
| HY5 | 01/08/2021 | Paid |
| NHY56 | 01/04/2021 | Paid |
| 5THJU | 01/08/2021 | Paid |
| GTK09 |  | Not Paid |
| NH987 | 01/06/2021 | Paid |
| 5THJU |  | Not Paid |
| HY5 | 2/1/2021 | Paid |
| HU980 |  | Not Paid |
| 5THJU |  | Not Paid |
| 5THJU |  | Not Paid |
| GTK09 | 10/4/2021 | Paid |
| 09KLH | 21/04/2021 | Paid |
| NH987 |  | Not Paid |

I have the above data in column A,B, and C
How can I find the 3 most unpaid accounts? I calculated the paid or unpaid by using

```
=IF(B2<>"","Paid","Not Paid")
```

Thanks for taking time.

Comment: I see you are trying to mark them all as correct, this does not work.  Choose the one that you used in the end to do this task.  None of us will get our feeling hurt if ours is not chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use `COUNTIFS` then sort largest to smallest.

Try: `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$19, $A2, $C$2:$C$19, "Not Paid")`

[image]

If there is a bunch of data, you could even do `=UNIQUE(data_range)` before sorting, and then copy paste values over themselves before sorting to get a better look.

Comment: Make sure your syntax is correct, you are referencing the correct columns, and you have the dollar signs in the right spot. See my picture to confirm the returns. In some cases, of course, the return will be zero (if the account does not have a "Not Paid")

Answer (score 3):

If one has Office 365 then we can use LET to do all the work in one go:

```
=LET(
    acct,A:A,
    sts,C:C,
    unq,UNIQUE(FILTER(acct,sts="Not Paid")),
    arr,CHOOSE({1,2},unq,COUNTIFS(acct,unq,sts,"Not Paid")),
    INDEX(SORT(arr,2,-1),{1;2;3},1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, add a dummy column with 1 in each row.

Highlight the data table, select `Insert` in your ribbon, and insert `PivotTable`.

Select the account and drag it to the bottom left, and drag the Status column to the top left and filter for 'Not Paid', then drag that dummy column into the bottom right.

Lastly, Sort by that column in the pivot table by select anywhere in the values section and hitting Z-->A in the `Data` tab of the ribbon. Alternatively you can filter on the value and select on the top 3 if you want an exclusive list of those accounts.

If you hit `CTRL` + `T` on the table in the beginning you convert it to the table format, so if this table gets updated, you won't need to reference the cell range for the pivot table, you can simply refresh it to update the values.

Comment: Im sorry. I have never used pivotTable, you think you can explain how I can drag columns in the table? (Select the account and drag it to the bottom left, and drag the Status column to the top left and filter for 'Not Paid', then drag that dummy column into the bottom right.)

Comment: It may seem intimidating but I've found them actually pretty intuitive and it's way quicker to get a quick summary of data in a low stakes setting. You don't need to write formulas or adjust data, simply drag and drop to experiment with different layouts. Just follow my steps and it will be straightforward.